# Cramer-Rao lower bound in a Gamma distribution

Tags: estimators, exponential-family, umvue

I have this Gamma density function:

$$\frac{1}{6\theta^8} x^3 \exp\Big[\frac{-1}{\theta^2}x\Big]$$

If I calculate the MSE I have that:

$$\hat\theta=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum{x_i}}$$

Now, if I calculate the Cramer Rao lower bound for this distribution, I have:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2\log(f(x))}{\partial\theta^2} &= \frac{8\theta^2-6x}{\theta^4}  \\[5pt]
-nE\bigg[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\log(f(x))\bigg] &= \frac{16n}{\theta^2}
\end{align}

Because $E(x)=4\theta^2$ then, Cramer Rao lower bound is equal to $\frac{\theta^2}{16n}$, but if I calculate the variance of $\hat\theta$ I have that as equal to $\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\frac{4\theta^2}{n}}=\frac{\theta}{2\sqrt{n}}$. I assumed that the variance of sample mean is ${\rm Var}(\bar{x})= \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$, where $\sigma^2$ indicates the variance of the population that is distributed as a $\Gamma(\theta^2,4)$. So ${\rm Var}(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\bar{x}})=(\frac{1}{2})^2\sqrt{\frac{4\theta^4}{n}}= \frac{2\theta^2}{4\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\theta^2}{2\sqrt{n}}$, which is different from the Cramer Rao lower bound $\frac{\theta^2}{ 16n}$

But if I write the density function in the form of the exponential family, I have:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{6\theta^8} x^3 \exp\Big[\frac{-1}{\theta^2}x\Big] &= \frac{1}{6}x^3 \exp\big[-\frac{1}{\theta^2}x-8\log\theta\big]  \\[5pt]
a(\theta) &= -\frac{1}{\theta^2}  \\[5pt]
t(x) &= x  \\[5pt]
c(\theta) &= -8\log\theta  \\[5pt]
-\frac{c'(\theta)}{a'(\theta} &= 4\theta^2
\end{align}

And I find that $\frac{1}{n}\sum{x_i}$ is the UMVUE estimator for $4\theta^2$.

And so I have that $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum{x_i}}$ is UMVUE estimator for $\theta$.

But how can it be possible if the variance of this estimator is different from the Cramer Rao lower bound?

Comment: Could you show how you compute the variance of $\hat\theta$?

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: What justifies your assumption about the variance of the sample mean and what is "$\sigma$"?  Moreover, $\hat \theta$ is *not* the sample mean--it's proportional to its *square root*. It begins to look like your question might be rooted in misconceptions concerning the definitions and calculations of moments, rather than in any paradoxical behavior of the Carmer-Rao bound.

Answer (score 1):

Remember an unbiased estimator that reaches the Cramer-Rao lower-bound is UMVUE, but if an estimator is UMVUE it does not necessarily reach the Cramer-Rao lower bound.